# Post and change Page

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

How can you post params to a page and call the target page without a form in **html**.

I have a link like this

```
<a href="#" class="post">Post</a>
```

and want post some information with **jQuery**

```
$('a.post').on('click', function() {    
$.ajax({
 'url'  : 'test.php',
 'type' : 'POST',
 'data' : {}
        }); 
});
```

This solution is working and i can post data but i cant goto the target page ('test.php'). I want goto test.php and POST the data.

Comment: tried a querystring? then you dont need to go to page

Comment: but i want go to the target page

Comment: before or after you post the information

Comment: Why do you need ajax if you intend to redirect to the target page. Seems a bit uneccessary. You could just post the data and do a window.location redirect on success, but that's probably not what you are looking for, you are probably looking for a regular form

Comment: @adeneo and kevin are correct! ajax is used for a postback to server not for moving you to a different page. your last edit to the question clarified this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why couldn't you use the anchor to navigate in this situation?  It seems to achieve your stated goal.

```
<a href="test.php?param1=a" class="post">Post</a>
```

Or if you really need to perform a post, use a form:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
  ...
</form>
```